# Visual studio 2015 tfs add files to source control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have the following issue-

On Team Explorer - Pending Changes there is an option that automatically detects added files to folders that are under source control. The problem is that more than 50,000 files are detected.

Is there any way to edit this list? to remove items I don't care about so it will be relevant when I do have files I want to add?

(I know I can add items in the Source Control but I want to make this option usable)

[image: Detected changes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click the '**Detected**' link to pop up the "Promote Candidate Changes" dialog, then select the files you want to check in to promote.

If you're using local workspaces, you can add a **.tfignore** file to ignore the files which you don't want to be detected in source control. eg: ignore by file extension .txt, then all the .txt files will be ignored in source control. They will not be detected.

Please see [Customize which files are ignored by version control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control) for details.

Please note that with TFVC you need to put **.tfignore** in every solution root.

> .tfignore file rules The following rules apply to a .tfignore file:
>
> # begins a comment line
>
> The * and ? wildcards are supported.
>
> A filespec is recursive unless prefixed by the \ character.
>
> ! negates a filespec (files that match the pattern are not ignored)

```
.tfignore file example

######################################
# Ignore .cpp files in the ProjA sub-folder and all its subfolders
ProjA\*.cpp
#
# Ignore .txt files in this folder
\*.txt
#
# Ignore .xml files in this folder and all its sub-folders
*.xml
#
# Ignore all files in the Temp sub-folder
\Temp
#
# Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!*.dll
```

[image]

Comment: @Ziv Weissman Currently we can only check/uncheck the files with the list in "Promote Candidate Changes" dialog to determine which files can be checked in, can not edit it externally.

Comment: Thanks, adding it by right click and choosing ignore - will add to the .tfignore? Also I want only on my machine to ignore these changes, will it work if the .tfignore is local only?

Comment: @ZivWeissman Yes, when you right click and choose ignore, it will automatically generate a .tfignore file under the solution root with the corresponding exclude settings. It works locally, just do not check in the .tfignore file if you just want to set the rule for yourself.